# Chart options do not work?

Tags: html, angular, charts, chart.js, angular5

I am having issues with the `NG2-Charts` module, it's a ngular wrapper for `charts.js`. None of the options I try to give my chart seem to work. I can change colors, labels and data without any issues.

I have exactly the same code as in the [line-chart example](https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/) except I add some options from the off

Markup:

```
<h2 class="page-header">Pie Bakery</h2>
<div class="container piechart">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div style="display: block;">
<!-- Rendering canvas chart -->
          <canvas baseChart width="400" height="400"
                      [datasets]="lineChartData"
                      [labels]="lineChartLabels"
                      [options]="lineChartOptions"
                      [colors]="lineChartColors"
                      [legend]="lineChartLegend"
                      [chartType]="lineChartType"
                      (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
                      (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
<!-- Done rendering canvas chart -->
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
          <table class="table table-responsive table-condensed">
            <tr>
              <th *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels">{{label}}</th>
            </tr>
            <tr *ngFor="let d of lineChartData">
              <td *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels; let j=index">{{d && d.data[j]}}</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <button (click)="randomize()">CLICK</button>
        </div>
      </div>  
</div>
```

Typescript:

```
// lineChart
  public lineChartData:Array<any> = [
    {data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40], label: 'Series A'},
    {data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90], label: 'Series B'},
    {data: [18, 48, 77, 9, 100, 27, 40], label: 'Series C'}
  ];

  public lineChartLabels:Array<any> = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'];
  public lineChartOptions:any = {
    responsive: true, // <- Without this the graph seems responsive as well.
    animation: false, // <- added more options.
    mode: 'nearest',
    cubicInterpolationMode: 'monotone',
    pointBorderColor: 'rgba(250, 0, 0,1)',
    lineTension: 0
  };  

  public lineChartColors:Array<any> = [
    { // grey
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.8)'
    },
    { // dark grey
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(77,83,96,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(77,83,96,1)',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(77,83,96,1)',
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(77,83,96,1)'
    },
    { // grey
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.8)'
    }
  ];

  public lineChartLegend:boolean = true;
  public lineChartType:string = 'line';

  public randomize():void {
    let _lineChartData:Array<any> = new Array(this.lineChartData.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < this.lineChartData.length; i++) {
      _lineChartData[i] = {data: new Array(this.lineChartData[i].data.length), label: this.lineChartData[i].label};
      for (let j = 0; j < this.lineChartData[i].data.length; j++) {
        _lineChartData[i].data[j] = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
      }
    }
    this.lineChartData = _lineChartData;
  }

    // events
    public chartClicked(e:any):void {
      console.log(e);
    }

    public chartHovered(e:any):void {
      console.log(e); // does not get called either.
    }
```

The default graph renders fine and the randomize button works also. Yet individually adding the different options or together like above does not make any difference.

There is an [old git issue from early 2016](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/issues/227) that addresses the problem of "some" options not working. Eventually the issue was closed since an update fixed it. I tried playing around with different builds of `charts.js` and `NG2-Charts` module without results.

Comment: Latest commit on that project was done 7 months ago an it has > 200 issues. I would not trust this library

Comment: use ng2-highcharts

Comment: As @Sajeetharan mentioned, or use swimlane's ngx-charts if you want to stick with chart.js library https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts

Comment: @Sajeetharan Isn't that a paid library? $430 seems a bit steep. At the moment it's for my port folio but the site has potential to be commercial.

Comment: @Z.Bagley thanks, I will try that out.